# Files have different revision numbers in Eclipse (Subversion)

Tags: eclipse, svn, revision

A commit in Subversion increments the revision number for all files by 1(correct me if i'm wrong). But when I look in Eclipse, I see that files have different revision numbers:

[image]

The revision number is behind the filename. Why is Eclipse showing different revision numbers for each file? I'm using the Subclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong in assuming that all files have the same revision number.

When committing some files the committed files all get a new revision number. This revision number is the next revision number for the repository used.

Now if you commit one file but not the other the first file gets a new number whereas the other file keeps the old number.

So in your image all files with the same revision number were committed at the dsame time. A higher revision number for a file means that this file was committed later than a file with a lower number.

So the displayed revision numbers are as expected.

Comment: Thx, thats explains it. I do find [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs) explanation confusing.

Comment: I find it's a lot clearer to state "last changed revision" for individual files because they *will* differ greatly, and "revision number" for the repository or a subdirectory as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

> Subversion working copies do not always correspond to any single
>   revision in the repository.

See ["Mixed-revision working copies"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs) SVNBook section.