# After committing a file the project revision remains unaltered. Is this a bug?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm just getting started with SVN after many years using CVS. As I understand it, the project revision number reflects the highest revision number of its contents.

As a test, I created a simple Java project and shared it using the 'multiple projects layout'. I notice that the decoration on the project is changed first (to rev12400) and then the contents (to rev12401). The project revision remains at 12400 which I don't understand. A refresh changes nothing but a look in the repository shows 12401 on the project. If I delete the project from the workspace and check out the project then it shows 12401.

Is this a bug or the expected behaviour?

- RAD8,
- Subversive SVN Team Provider 1.0.0.I20130122-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group
- Subversive SVN Connectors    3.0.0.I20120601-1700 org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group

Comment: possible duplicate of [Files have different revision numbers in Eclipse (Subversion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882270/files-have-different-revision-numbers-in-eclipse-subversion)

Comment: @uweplonus - my question is different. I DON'T expect ALL files to have the SAME revision number. What I DO expect is that the project revision number should be the SAME as the HIGHEST revision number of the files it contains. Is this correct?

Comment: @UwePlonus - ok, but can you explain why the project then DOES have the changed (higher) revision number when I view the repository?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different sides of subversion: the server side and the client side.

If you look at the server your assumption is correct. The revision number of any folder is the highest reision number of all content in the folder.

If you now check out your repository the numbers from the server is reflected on your local revision numbers.

If you now change any file then tis file gets a new revision number from the server and this is reflected on the client side. A change to a folder is only counted when there is a structural change to the folder. Else the folder on the client side will sta with the same revision number as before.

So for subversion it is normal that the revision number of a folder may be different on client and server if you worked with the checked out sources.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I find it strange that my client does not reflect the true state of the project. How do I tell a coworker to use revX (as seen on my client) when actually on the server the version is X+1? I'm trying to create a walkthru to help colleagues to migrate from CVS - that's why I'm being picky ;-)

Comment: @paul Use a timestamp or tag to check out a certain revision. The revision numbers are not really helpful on this.